# navigate to screen from button in header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have setup a basic header using react-navigation:

```
class HeaderRight extends Component {

  navigateToScreen() {
     // Navigate to different screen
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
          this.navigateToScreen(true)
        }}>
          <Image source={require('../images/home-icon.png')}  style={{width: 30, height: 30}} />
        </TouchableHighlight>

    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click the image how do I open another screen that animates from the left of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
navigateToScreen()
{
  this.props.navigator.push({ transitionType : 'PushFromRight', id : 'YOUR SCREEN ID' });
}
render() {
    return (
    <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.navigateToScreen()}>
          <Image source={require('../images/home-icon.png')}  style={{width: 30, height: 30}} />
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
    );
  }
```

here i have used Navigator for android.
and already setup Navigator Ids for all the screen so first you have to set up that ids for your screen

Thank you.